# Процесс создания класса - потомка в Java

Tags: java, классы, наследование

Куда ссылается this в System.out.println("end of creating C (this.name): " + this.name)? и почему this в this.name и просто this ссылаются на разные объекты, исходя из вывода на консоль? как в C, так и в В.
вывод     System.out.println("end of creating C (this.name): " + this.name)     - "end of creating C (this.name): CS", вывод     System.out.println("C.this : " + this)     - "C.this : AS".

```
    public class Solution {
       public static class A {
       String name = "A";

       public A(String name) {
           this.name += name;
           System.out.println("end of creating A (this.name): " + this.name);
           System.out.println("A.this : " + this);
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() { // если toString закомментировать, то везде видно, что this ссылается на объект, который "спускается" из А.
           System.out.println("in toString: " + name);
           return name;
       }
   }

   public static class B extends A {
          String name = "B";

       public B(String name) {
           super(name);
           this.name += name;
           System.out.println("end of creating B (this.name): " + this.name);
           System.out.println("B.this : " + this);
       }
   }

   public static class C extends B {
       String name = "C";

       public C(String name) {
           super(name);
           this.name += name;
           System.out.println("end of creating C (this.name): " + this.name);
           System.out.println("C.this : " + this);
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(new C ("S"));
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` в контексте `System.out.println(this)` = выполнение метода `toString()`. Метод `toString()` есть у любого объекта в языке `java`. Это базовый метод - представляет объект как строку. Иногда он переопределён - как у вас в классе `"А"`. Вообще, для понимания как работает программа часто лучше использовать отладчик, чем SO - как пользоваться отладчиком [разбирается на youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z1BQsf0A4xY).

Давайте по порядку:

**1.** `public static void main(String[] args)` - является точкой входа. Компилятор будет начинать отсюда чтение.

**2.** Он заходит в метод  `System.out.println(new C ("S")):`

**2.1** Он ещё ничего не выводит на консоль. Он создаёт новый объект `new C` передавая в конструктор строку `"S"`

**3.** Мы попали в конструктор **С** (в этом моменте, у нас в консоль по-прежнему ничего не вывелось). В этот конструктор прилетел параметр "S".  Команда `super(name)` - вызывает конструктор супер класса. Теперь на этом шаге, мы ещё не выполнили конструктор класса "С" а уже залетели в конструктор класса **B**.

**4.** Мы начали выполнять конструктор класса **B** (туда прилетел параметр "S") по строчно. Первой мы выполняем строчку  `super(name)` - она снова дёргает конструктор супер-класса. Так, не выполнив конструктор класса **B** - мы перешли в конструктор класса **А**, куда снова прилетел параметр "S".
 **5.** Мы начинаем выполнять, строка за строкой конструктор класса "А":

**5.1** Сначала записал в его поля `name` параметр "S": было его имя "А" стало "АS";

**5.2** И вот, в консоль выводим первую строчку: `"end of creating A (this.name): AS"`

**5.3** Следующую строчку пытаемся вывести выводим: "A this: + this" - у нас не получается так сразу, потому что this - это, по умолчанию, указание на объект. Но если метод toString переопределён (а он у вас в классе переопределён) - то this вернёт результат работы метода toString; Выполняется метод toString:

**5.3.1** Метод `toString()` выполняется и выводит вам на консоль `in toString: AS` - затем возвращает вам строку name (оно всё ещё AS) в "A this: + this". То есть вместо +this вам выводит `A this: AS`.

**6.** Промежуточный итог: вы находитесь около правой скобки конструктора А (конструктор А выполнился, мы возвращаемся в конструктор B, ту самую точку, ОТКУДА БЫЛ ВЫЗВАН А. У вас в консоли OUTPUT:

```
 end of creating A (this.name):AS
 in toString: AS
 A this: AS
```

**7.** Вы находитесь в конструкторе B после слова супер. В поле String name объекта B перезаписывается имя. Было "B", стало "BS".

**8.** На консоль выводится строчка "end of creating B BS " - BS вернула команда B.name;

**9.** В соответствии с парадигмой наследования, те методы которые имеет объект класса - родителя, имеет и объект класса потомка. То есть, в классе "B" и в классе "С" метод toString() тоже переопределен - он тот же, что и в классе **А**. И всякий раз, когда вы дёргаете ссылкой **this** объект класса B или C у вас будет выполнятся метод `toString()` определённый в классе А:

`in toString: AS` - это поведение очень интересно. В соответствии с парадигмой наследования, поля не переопределяются, а перекрываются. То есть, у объекта класса "B" есть два поля name, условно Aname и Bname. У объекта класса "С" будет три поля name:Aname, Bname и Сname. Но так, как метод `toString` переопределён только в классе "А", при выполнении метода `toString` он дёргает то поле `name` - до которого дотягивается. Неформально в нём зашито не просто дёрнуть поле, а дёрнуть по ссылке `this` т.е. name понимается как `this.name`. Если ссылка `this` указана в методе класса "А" наверное вам понятно, что она дёрнет поле `name` класса **А** в данном случае `AS`.  На консоль выведется строчка вроде `B.this : AS` - метод toString вернул поле Aname.

**10.** Мы выполняем конструктор "C" после слова супер. Выполнив конструктор "B" программа вернулась в ту точку, из которой была вызвана.   this.name += name; переписала поле name c "C" на СS;

**11.** На консоль вывелась `end of creating C (this.name): СS - потому что поле name переписалось

**12.** Вывелось на консоль `in toString: AS` - по той же причине, что и в классе "B" - ссылка this дёрнула метод toString().

**13.** C.this : AS - метод toString() опять вернул поле Aname.

**14.** Мы вышли из конструктора "С" - попали туда, откуда вызвали этот конструктор. В точку входа. Система хочет распечатать объект "C". Чтобы его распечатать снова дёргается метод toSting() который распечатывает Aname:`in toString: AS` и возвращает Aname который распечатывается в public static void main как `AS`

Comment: но если toString закомментировать, видно, что this везде ссылается на одно и то же место в памяти. Собственно вопрос - у какого объекта дергается поле name, если вызвать его в конструкторе по this.name? правильно ли я понимаю, что создается в итоге 3 объекта?

Comment: Процесс создания объекта new C не подразумевает создание другого объекта A или B. Вы создали один объект С, со свойствами A и B. Естественно любой вызов this для него - это вызов одного и того же метода toString(). Хоть вы закоментили, хоть нет - метод toString() есть по умолчанию в каждом объекте.

Comment: А раз у вас один объект - то соответственно лежит он в одном месте в памяти.

Comment: но в пункте 9 вы ведете речь об объектах классов A, B и С. или здесь подразумевается какие-то гипотетические объекты этих классов? действительно, объект создается один - проверил выводом this во всех местах. Переопределил toString в B, в С вывелось BS. спасибо!

Comment: Гипотетические объекты. Создание объектов происходит тогда и только тогда, когда где-нибудь отрабатывает оператор new. У вас он отрабатывает только в main. Выполнение конструкторов родительского класса - это обязательная практика при создании объектов класса наследника.

Comment: еще вопрос, если можно. если переопределить toString только в C и создать объект, to все выводы в А и в В выводят null. Почему так?

Comment: return name так вы переопределили метод toString похоже. Указатель на имя конечного объекта. Дёргается поле Cname. Обратите внимание, что до загрузки конструкторов базового класса, Сname прогрузилась как null. Момент инициализации "С" - сразу после слова супер, конструктора "С".  В конструкторе "А" вы дёргаете полусозданный объект "С" метод которого toString возвращает Cname.